# Incorrect data being received on RX of NRF24L01P

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, spi, nrf24l01+, wireless

I am running a setup of two NRF24L01P's on homemade code where the TX sends an analog signal fed through a standard pot, and the RX simply prints out the signal. But the RX seems to be getting incorrect data, meaning that where the centre value on TX side is 670, the centre value on RX side is 180. Why is this happening? I have auto acknowledgement, and dynamic payload enabled. I also tried setting 250KBPS and 2000KBPS with the max power setting, and still the results dont change. Is this because of loss of power in the wireless communication? Will a voltage follower be needed?

Function definitions in code:

```
/* CONNECTIONS
 * NRF    ARDUINO
 * GND    GND
 * VCC    VCC
 * CE     D7
 * CSN    D8
 * MOSI   D11
 * SCK    D13
 * MISO ``D12
 * IRQ    D2*/

 #include <SPI.h>
 #define CE_PIN 7
 #define CSN_PIN 8
 #define MOSI_PIN 11
 #define SCK_PIN 13
 #define MISO_PIN 12
 #define W_REGISTER B00100000
 #define R_RX_PAYLOAD B01100001
 #define W_TX_PAYLOAD B10100000
 #define FLUSH_TX B11100001
 #define FLUSH_RX B11100010
 #define RF_SETUP 0x06
 #define RF_DR_LOW 5
 #define RF_DR_HIGH 3
 #define RF_CH 0x05
 #define EN_RXADDR 0x02
 #define ERX_P0 0
 #define SETUP_AW 0x03
 #define RX_ADDR_P0 0x0A
 #define FEATURE 0x1D
 #define EN_DPL 2
 #define EN_AA 0x01
 #define CONFIG 0x00
 #define PWR_UP 1
 #define PRIM_RX 0
 #define MASK_RX_DR 6
 #define MASK_TX_DS 5
 #define MASK_MAX_RT 4
 #define EN_CRC 3
 #define CRCO 2
 #define STATUS 0x07
 #define RX_DR 6
 #define TX_DS 5
 #define MAX_RT 4
 #define NOP B11111111
 #define TX_ADDR 0x10
 #define DYNPD 0x1C


 byte data_buff;
 int address = 123;
 byte data_recieve;


//******************************** write a byte to a regster *******************************
void writeRegister(byte reg_address, byte data)
{
  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(W_REGISTER | reg_address);
  SPI.transfer(data);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);
}

//******************************* set the air data rate *******************************
void setAirDataRate(int air_data_rate)
{
  switch(air_data_rate)
  {

    case 250:
     setRegisterBit(RF_SETUP, RF_DR_LOW, 1);
     setRegisterBit(RF_SETUP, RF_DR_HIGH, 0);
     break;

    case 1000:
     setRegisterBit(RF_SETUP, RF_DR_LOW, 0);
     setRegisterBit(RF_SETUP, RF_DR_HIGH, 0);
     break;

    case 2000:
      setRegisterBit(RF_SETUP, RF_DR_LOW, 0);
      setRegisterBit(RF_SETUP, RF_DR_HIGH, 1);
      break;

    default:
      Serial.println("WRONG AIR DATA RATE ENTERED!");
      break;
  }
}

void setRegisterBit(byte reg_address, byte bit_add, byte bit_val)
{
  getRegisterStat(reg_address);

  if(bit_val == 1)
  {
    bitSet(data_buff, bit_add);
  }

  else
  {
    bitClear(data_buff, bit_add);
  }

  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(W_REGISTER | reg_address);
  SPI.transfer(data_buff);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);

  Serial.print(bit_add);
  Serial.print(" bit set to ");
  Serial.print(bit_val);
  Serial.print(" in register ");
  Serial.println(reg_address);
}

void getRegisterStat(byte reg_address)
{
  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(reg_address);
  data_buff = SPI.transfer(0);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);
}

void enableDPL( int pipe_number)
{
  setRegisterBit(FEATURE, EN_DPL, 1); //enable dpl by EN_DPL = 1
  setRegisterBit(DYNPD, pipe_number, 1); //DPL_Px = 1
}

void openReadingPipe()
{
  setRegisterBit(EN_RXADDR, 0, 1); //ERX_P0 = 1
  writeRegister(RX_ADDR_P0, address);//set address for datapipe
  Serial.print("Data Pipe open with address:  ");
  Serial.println(address);
}

void openWritingPipe()
{
  setRegisterBit(EN_RXADDR, 0, 1); //ERX_Px = 1
  writeRegister(TX_ADDR, address);//set address for datapipe
  writeRegister(RX_ADDR_P0, address);
}

//******************************* set the frequency *******************************
void setChannelFreq(int frequency)
{
  int  frequency_val = frequency - 2400;
  if(frequency_val <= 125 && frequency_val > 0)
  {
    writeRegister(RF_CH, frequency_val);
  }

  else
    Serial.println("WRONG FREQUENCY VALUE ENTERED!");
}

//******************************* print the status of the register *******************************
void printRegStatus(byte reg_address)
{
  getRegisterStat(reg_address);

  switch(reg_address)
  {
    case RF_SETUP:
    bitRead(data_buff, 3) ? Serial.println("AIR DATA RATE SET TO 2000KBPS") : bitRead(data_buff, 5) ? Serial.println("AIR DATA RATE SET TO 250KBPS") : Serial.println("AIR DATA RATE SET TO 1000KBPS");
    break;

    case EN_RXADDR:
    bitRead(data_buff, 0) ? Serial.print("Data Pipe 0 open with address:  ") : Serial.print("Data Pipe 0 not open with address:  ");
    Serial.println(address);
    break;

    case RF_CH:
    Serial.print("The set frequency is:");
    Serial.println(2400 + data_buff);
    break;

    case CONFIG:
    bitRead(data_buff, MASK_RX_DR) ? Serial.println("RX_DR interrupt not reflected on IRQ") : Serial.println("RX_DR interrupt is active low on IRQ");
    bitRead(data_buff, MASK_TX_DS) ? Serial.println("TX_DS interrupt not reflected on IRQ") : Serial.println("TX_DS interrupt is active low on IRQ");
    bitRead(data_buff, MASK_MAX_RT) ? Serial.println("MAX_RT interrupt not reflected on IRQ") : Serial.println("MAX_RT interrupt is active low on IRQ");
    bitRead(data_buff, EN_CRC) ? Serial.println("CRC is Enabled!") : Serial.println("CRC is diabled!");
    bitRead(data_buff, CRCO) ? Serial.println("CRC is 2 bytes.") : Serial.println("CRC is 1 byte.");
    break;

     case EN_AA:
    bitRead(data_buff, 0) ? Serial.println("ENABLE AUTO ACK ON PIPE 0") : Serial.println("AUTO ACK NOT ENABLED");
    break;

    case FEATURE:
    bitRead(data_buff, EN_DPL) ? Serial.println("DYNAMIC PAYLOAD LENGTH ENABLED") : Serial.println("DYNAMIC PAYLOAD LENGTH NOT ENABLED!");
    break;

    case DYNPD:
    bitRead(data_buff, 0) ? Serial.println("DYNAMIC PAYLOAD ON DATA PIPE 0 ENABLED!") : Serial.println("DYNAMIC PAYLOAD NOT ENABLED IN DATA PIPE!");
    break;

    case TX_ADDR:
    Serial.print("ADDRESS: ");Serial.println(data_buff);
    break;

    case RX_ADDR_P0:
    Serial.print("ADDRESS: ");Serial.println(data_buff);
    break;

    case SETUP_AW:
    if(bitRead(data_buff, 1) == 0 && bitRead(data_buff, 0 == 1))
    Serial.println("ADDRESS WIDTH 3 BYTES!");
    break;


  }
}

//******************************* set the address width *******************************
void setAddressWidth(byte address_width)
{
  switch(address_width)
  {
    //addres width is 3 bytes
    case 3:
    setRegisterBit(SETUP_AW, 0, 1);
    setRegisterBit(SETUP_AW, 1, 0);
    break;

    //address width is 4 bytes
    case 4:
    setRegisterBit(SETUP_AW, 0, 0);
    setRegisterBit(SETUP_AW, 1, 1);
    break;

    //address width is 5 bytes
    case 5:
    setRegisterBit(SETUP_AW, 0, 1);
    setRegisterBit(SETUP_AW, 1, 1);
    break;

    default:
    Serial.println("WRONG ADDRESS WIDTH ENTERED!");
    break;
  }
}

//******************************** enable auto acknowledgment *******************************
void enableAutoACK()
{
  setRegisterBit(EN_AA, 0, 1);
}

//******************************** enable auto acknowledgment *******************************
void clearInterrupts()
{
  setRegisterBit(STATUS, RX_DR, 1);
  setRegisterBit(STATUS, TX_DS, 1);
  setRegisterBit(STATUS, MAX_RT, 1);
}

void confirmTransmit()
{
  Serial.print("PACKET SENT SUCCESSFULLY!!");
  setRegisterBit(STATUS, TX_DS, 1);

}

void setupRadio(int air_data_rate, int frequency, byte address_width)  //air data rate in kbps, frequency in MHz, address width in bytes
{

  DDRB = B00101001;
  DDRD = B10000000;
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();
  //set air data rate
  setAirDataRate(air_data_rate);

  //set frequency
  setChannelFreq(frequency);

  //set address width
  setAddressWidth(address_width);

  //flush the rx and tx fifo
  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(FLUSH_RX);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);

  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(FLUSH_TX);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);

  //enable dpl
  enableDPL(0);

  //enable CRC
  setRegisterBit(CONFIG, EN_CRC, 1);
  setRegisterBit(CONFIG, CRCO, 0);

  bitClear(PORTD, 7); //set CE low
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);// keep CSN high
}

//******************************** setup the RX *******************************
void setupRX()
{
    //open up the pipe for transmission
    openReadingPipe();

    //mask tx and max rt IRQ
    setRegisterBit(CONFIG, MASK_MAX_RT, 1);
    setRegisterBit(CONFIG, MASK_TX_DS, 1);

    //power up module
    setRegisterBit(CONFIG, PWR_UP, 1);

    //Tpd2stby delay
    delay(5);

    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), recieveData, FALLING);

    //clear any interrupt flag
    clearInterrupts();

    //set PRIM_RX bit
    setRegisterBit(CONFIG, PRIM_RX, 1);
    bitSet(PORTD, 7); //set CE high
    delay(1);
}

//******************************** setup the TX *******************************
void setupTX()
{
  openWritingPipe();
  setRegisterBit(CONFIG, PRIM_RX, 0);

  //mask rx and max rt interrupt
  setRegisterBit(CONFIG, MASK_RX_DR, 1);
  setRegisterBit(CONFIG, MASK_MAX_RT, 1);

  //enable autoACK
  enableAutoACK();

  setRegisterBit(RF_SETUP, 2, 1);
  setRegisterBit(RF_SETUP, 1, 1);
  setRegisterBit(CONFIG, PWR_UP, 1);

  delay(5);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(3), confirmTransmit, FALLING);

  clearInterrupts();
  delay(1);
}

//******************************** read data from RX FIFO *******************************
void recieveData()
{
  Serial.println("RECIEVE ISR BEGUN");

  bitClear(PORTD, 7); //set CE_PIN low
  delayMicroseconds(100);

  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(R_RX_PAYLOAD);
  data_recieve = SPI.transfer(NOP);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);

  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(RPD);
  data_buff = SPI.transfer(NOP);
  delay(1);
  bitSet(PORTB, 1);

  bitRead(data_buff, 0) ? Serial.println("THERE IS ENOUGH POWER!") : 
  Serial.println("THERE IS NOT ENOUGH POWER!");


  delayMicroseconds(15000);
  setRegisterBit(STATUS, RX_DR, 1);


  bitSet(PORTD, 7);
  delayMicroseconds(100);

  Serial.print("THROTTLE :");
  Serial.println(data_recieve);
 }
//******************************** write data to be transmitted *******************************
void transmitData(byte data)
{
  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(FLUSH_TX);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);

  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(W_TX_PAYLOAD);
  SPI.transfer(data);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);

  bitSet(PORTD, 7);
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
  bitClear(PORTD, 7);

  delayMicroseconds(130);

  /*bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x17);
  data_buff = SPI.transfer(NOP);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);
  bitRead(data_buff, 4) ? Serial.println("TX FIFO EMPTY!") : 
  Serial.println("DATA IN TX FIFO");*/
}
```

The RX code (all function definitions are same obviously):

```
void setup(){
  setupRadio(1000, 2515, 3);
  setupRX();
 /*printRegStatus(CONFIG);
 printRegStatus(TX_ADDR);
 printRegStatus(RX_ADDR_P0);
 printRegStatus(EN_AA);
 printRegStatus(RF_CH);
 printRegStatus(FEATURE);
 printRegStatus(RF_SETUP);
 printRegStatus(SETUP_AW);*/

}

void loop(){

 delay(1000);
}
```

The TX code (all function definitions are same obviously):

```
void setup(){
      setupRadio(1000, 2515, 3);
      setupTX();
     /*printRegStatus(CONFIG);
     printRegStatus(TX_ADDR);
     printRegStatus(RX_ADDR_P0);
     printRegStatus(EN_AA);
     printRegStatus(RF_CH);
     printRegStatus(FEATURE);
     printRegStatus(RF_SETUP);
     printRegStatus(SETUP_AW);
     printRegStatus(DYNPD);*/

    }

    void loop(){
     int throttle_raw = sqrt(pow(analogRead(A2), 2) + pow(analogRead(A3), 2));
      transmitData(throttle_raw);
      Serial.println(throttle_raw);
      delay(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Probably has to do with the fact that you're passing an `int`-sized parameter to a function that takes a byte. Your `transmitData()` doesn't take multi-byte values into account. Why not use existing libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new TX function:

```
void transmitData(byte * data, byte len)
{
  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(FLUSH_TX);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);

  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(W_TX_PAYLOAD);

  len = min(len, 32); // since 32 is max size
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    SPI.transfer(*data++);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);

  bitSet(PORTD, 7);
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
  bitClear(PORTD, 7);

  delayMicroseconds(130);

  /*bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x17);
  data_buff = SPI.transfer(NOP);
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);
  bitRead(data_buff, 4) ? Serial.println("TX FIFO EMPTY!") : 
  Serial.println("DATA IN TX FIFO");*/
}
```

To receive data with dynamic payloads enabled, you need to know the size of the incoming payload before you read. Study `getDynamicPayloadSize()` in the RF24 library and pass the value returned as the second argument to the RX function below. Your new RX function should look like this:

```
void recieveData(byte * data, byte len)
{
  Serial.println("RECIEVE ISR BEGUN");

  bitClear(PORTD, 7); //set CE_PIN low
  delayMicroseconds(100);

  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(R_RX_PAYLOAD);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    *data = SPI.transfer(0xff); data++;
  }
  bitSet(PORTB, 0);

  bitClear(PORTB, 0);
  SPI.transfer(RPD);
  data_buff = SPI.transfer(NOP);
  delay(1);
  bitSet(PORTB, 1);

  bitRead(data_buff, 0) ? Serial.println("THERE IS ENOUGH POWER!") : 
  Serial.println("THERE IS NOT ENOUGH POWER!");


  delayMicroseconds(15000);
  setRegisterBit(STATUS, RX_DR, 1);


  bitSet(PORTD, 7);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
 }
```

In both functions, you pass in buffers to hold the data you want to send or receive. In your case, since you're sending `int`s, a call like this `transmitData(&throttle, 2)` should do. Since you already know the size of what you're sending, you can simply pass 2 as length to `receiveData()` and skip querying the payload size like this `receiveData(&throttle, 2)`. Casting will be done implicitly.

If, in fact, `receiveData` is an ISR like your comments say (maybe you're using some IRQ pin), you'll have to split it in two; one part to handle the interrupt quickly by setting an `available` flag or something (obviously taking no arguments) to be polled in `loop()` and another to actually `read` the data. Or you can just setup the buffer as a global thing and hard-code a 2-byte read in the ISR. Though I have to say your maybe-ISR is terrible, what with huge delays and prints everywhere and I don't know how it manages to work at all.

Basically, if you want to understand the chip, it doesn't hurt to look at existing code to understand the 'right' way to do stuff.

Comment: In RF24, why does he define the parameter for the buffer in write_payload as a void* ?

Comment: @BabaYaga So that you can pass a pointer to any sort of data type without needing to cast it first. Casting is done within write_payload().